# Ubuntu 13.04 is really slow on the window7

Tags: installation, boot

I have recently installed ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop.

Specs:

- Windows 7
- Core i5
- 4gb RAM
- 500gb hard disk.

Ever since I have installed Ubuntu, it has been responding really slow. I installed it using the virtual box and didn't dual boot.

Will defragmentation help?

Comment: Is it for long term use? If so I recommend setting up the dual boot. Then you have the option to select what operating system you want at start up. If not Increase your ram that will probably solve the problem. Its most likely your computer cant handle a VM. -Chetwynd

Comment: What exactly is slow? Your host OS Windows or the guest OS Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to increase the RAM size of the virtual machine. Usually virtual machine is not as faster as it is installed on a seperate partition. And this case gets worse since you have installed a latest ubuntu version. You should allocate more memory for the VM.